# Error on while Installing SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, installation, clustered-index

[image]

I am getting this error when I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/6b28185a-88bb-480d-8ac9-7b695e347d75

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverClustering/thread/9cb1308d-edd0-44e5-a10e-dfb9f10a1ef3

these links might be helpful